# Swift - Parsing Json - Get values

Tags: json, xcode, swift, parsing, web

i started working with the SwiftyJson Class in order to parse json from the web.

I started with this RestApiManager:

```
typealias ServiceResponse = (JSON, NSError?) -> Void

class RestApiManager: NSObject {

    static let sharedInstance = RestApiManager()

    let baseUrl = "http://api.randomuser.me/"

    func getRandomUser(onCompletion: (JSON) -> Void) {

        makeHttpGetRequest(baseUrl, onCompletion: { json, err -> Void in

            onCompletion(json)

        })

    }

    func makeHttpGetRequest(path: String, onCompletion: ServiceResponse) {

        let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: path)!)

        let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()

        let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler: { data, response, error in

            let json: JSON = JSON(data)

            onCompletion(json, error)

        })

        task.resume()

    }

}
```

In my controller i called this method:

```
    RestApiManager.sharedInstance.getRandomUser { json -> Void in

        let results = json["results"]

        for (index: String, subJson: JSON) in results {

            println(subJson["user"]["gender"].stringValue)

        }

    }
```

But it just prints

```
(lldb)
```

and some useless information..

Anybody could help me with this problem?

I learned with this tutorial

```
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YX9vK11oX-E
```

and this git link:

```
https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON
```

Comment: Anybody could help me with this? Thanks for downvote...

Comment: Upvoted for you.  Sorry you may have to deal with fairly frequent downvote abuse on this site.